# What are the risks and risk chances of stopping chkdisk /r /f c:

Tags: windows-10, chkdsk

It's been stuck at 11% for hours, and I'm told there's a risk of data loss even if it finishes. What exactly is the risk of interrupting (powering down) if the scan appears to hang like this?

Note I have no keyboard control, as Windows has not yet booted up.

Comment: Depending on the size and stability of your drive a chkdsk can take *many* hours (I've seen it take 60 hours and finish). I recommend letting it run, however the risks of interruption are very minor. Chkdsk is resilient and doesn't remove data or change addresses until after actions are performed, so the worst case is really no worse than the drive stability already was prior to running it.

Comment: @shawn Very informative. Thanks for the reply. Maybe make your comment into a thread reply?